# Calculate the slope from a point on each parallel line and the distance between them

Tags: geometry

I have two parallel lines. I know one point on each line. Unlike similar questions, I know the distance between them. Can I determine the slope? Intuitively it seems like I can: If I have a metal bar of a constant width and two pins, there only seems to be two ways that I can position the bar so that it touches both pins. The metal bar acts like a pair of parallel lines a known distance apart, and each pin acts like a point on each line, whereas having two ways to do something looks like a solution involving a square root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Let your points be $A$ and $B$ and the distance between the lines be $d$. Take a unit vector $n=(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$ perpendicular to the lines. What you want is the scalar projection of $AB=(u,v)$ onto $n$ to be $d$:
$$
AB\cdot n=(u,v)\cdot (\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)=u\cos\alpha+v\sin\alpha=d.
$$
Dividing by $\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ and letting $\phi$ be such that
$$
\sin\phi=u/\sqrt{u^2+v^2},\quad \cos\phi=v/\sqrt{u^2+v^2}
$$
(there is only one such angle in $[0,2\pi)$) you have
$$
\sin(\alpha+\phi)=d/\sqrt{u^2+v^2},
$$
and from there you get the possible values of $\alpha$. So the slope(s) of your lines are $m=-\cot\alpha$ for the two found values of $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Can you help me out a bit more by explaining what (u, v) are and how they relate to my points?

Comment: $(u,v)$ are the coordinates of the vector $AB=B-A$ If $A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$, then $u=x_2-x_1$ and $v=y_2-y_1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and your elaboration. It works almost perfectly. The only thing is that the slope I calculate is perpendicular to slope I want. Easily fixed. But I'm not sure if it's some mistake you've made in your description, or some mistake I've made in implementing it.

Comment: You are right. The cos and the sine were flipped in the definition of $\phi$. I edited it.